# Bigquery Get result of multiple columns as a single row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which contains columns as

- order_num.line_item,event_id,po_num,dbd_flag,carrier etc.

I want to get the records in a single row from multiple columns. For example order_num and line_item together uniquely identifies a row. An order can have multiple events. Some events have Po_num , others may have db_flag etc.

for example for order_num as 1,line_item 1, event_id as 1 dbd_flag is 1 and rest fields are blank.

for order_num as 1,line_item 1, event_id as 3 po_num is 'some value' and rest fields are blank.

I want to have result set as order_num,po_num,dbd_value.carrier wherever they are available for that order in a single row.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would really help your question make sense to other people.

Comment: As @Gordon suggested, desired results as well as more details in your post will allow more community member to assist you with your question. In its current state, it seems like you want a "SELECT order_num, line_item from TABLE where [...]", but that doesn't seem to be what you really want.